# Asynchronous Execution of Feature file in Karate

Tags: karate

I have a activity where I am using Karate Mocks.
One of the API returns a response but then it also calls another API after some delay(Simulating processing of a Workload)

I want to achieve following :

```
Client --> Calls Karate Mock (Call A)
Client <-- Karate Mock Returns
----Interaction ends here ----

After 30 seconds or so..
Client Listener <-- Karate Mocks Posts (Call B)
```

What I am at currently is

```
Blocking: 

Client --> Calls Karate Mock (Call A)
Client Listener <-- Karate Mocks Posts (Call B)
Client <-- Karate Mock Returns (This is blocked until Call B happens)
```

have Call B in a separate Feature file and I can call it from another feature file.

So I guess I am struggling with Async calls in Karate.

I did created a Java class which achieves Asynchronous execution but I am not sure How can I call a Feature file from it. 
That would immediately solve this for me.

Also if there is better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be easy actually, use Java threads and this example should make it clear:

```
Scenario: pathMatches('/hardcoded')
    * def response = { hello: 'world' }
    * def fun = function(){ karate.log('*** before'); java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000); karate.log('*** after') }
    * eval new java.lang.Thread(fun).start()
```

Note that a JS `function(){}` gets auto-converted to a Java runnable, which is convenient. You should be able to invoke a second feature from the JS function using `karate.call()` which does the work of the POST you need.

Comment: pure Joy, Awesome!   Thank you!