# Execute Karate scenarios and wait until they are finished to return values

Tags: karate

I'm trying to run my scenarios asynchronously and I found this very useful [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54331602/22511456), but the problem is that after a few statements I need the thread to finish executing before proceeding further.

What I need are the following:

```
Scenario: Demo1
    * def fun = function(){ karate.call('@something', { someValue: 'Hello'}); }
    * eval new java.lang.Thread(fun).start()
    * print 'Fist Something'
    * print 'Second Something'
    * print 'Third Something'
    * wait until this eval new java.lang.Thread(fun).start() is finished before continuing from this point
    * print 'Fourth Something'
```

There are also scenarios where I need a value to be returned until some methods finish executing.

```
Scenario: Demo2
    * def username = ''
    * def fun = 
    """
      function(){ 
        var responseObject = karate.call('@prepareSomething', { someValue: 'SomeValue'}); 
        karate.set('username', responseObject.username);
      }
    """
    * eval new java.lang.Thread(fun).start()
    * print 'Fist Something'
    * print 'Second Something'
    * print 'Third Something'
    * wait until this eval new java.lang.Thread(fun).start() is finished before continuing from this point
    * print 'Fourth Something'
```

Any guidance will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at this example: https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1417023536082812935

Ignore the ActiveMQ part, but you see how you can use some Java helper code that takes care of forking a thread and using a `CompletableFuture` to "block" until some work has been completed on a different thread etc.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your reply, I posted the updates based on your example but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @DevSoftQA there are some known issues with JS and parallel threads. first, please try karate 1.4.1.RC3 ( refer https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2329 ) and then you have to try avoid JS functions on the "karate side" as far as possible, it should be possible if you refactor things a bit